# Почему через Геокодер не получается найти организацию?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api, yandex-places-api

Я преобразую текст в координаты при помощи geocode, после чего рисую метку.
Но пользователи "преобразуют" текст в координаты при помощи яндекс-карт. По одному и тому же запросу получаеются разные координаты (в яндекс-картах и при использовании geocode).

фиддл с использованием геокода:

```
...
let geocode = await ymaps.geocode('картодром фирсановка', {json: true});
let coords = geocode.GeoObjectCollection.metaDataProperty.GeocoderResponseMetaData.Point.coordinates.reverse();
point.geometry.setCoordinates(coords);
yMap.setCenter(coords);
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1v3fw53m/235/

Ссылка на карту с ТЕМ ЖЕ запросом:
https://yandex.ru/maps/216/zelenograd/?ll=37.254842%2C55.971234&z=16&mode=search&text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&sll=37.254842%2C55.971234&sspn=0.027637%2C0.014416&ol=biz&oid=219586516291&sctx=ZAAAAAgBEAAaKAoSCdo5lKEqlkJAEUMQIXU7X0xAEhIJAP%2F%2F%2F%2F9MzD8RAJATVMjtvD8iBAABAgQoBTABOOrFu%2BTS8JKFxQFA1wFIAVXNzMw%2BWABqAnJ1cACdAexRuD2gAQCoAQA%3D

Каким образом я могу получить из АПИ такой же результат, как и при обычном поиске?

Comment: а что вы хотите? вы просто рисуете карту по координатам полученным по тексту? а маркер вы не ресуете

Comment: маркер нарисован в фиддле, смотрите внимательнее. Я хочу чтобы маркер в фиддле и маркер на карте (ссылка есть в вопросе) находились в одном месте (т.к. тексты запросов одинаковые).

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь для рисования маркера используется метод `Placemark`,  а я сейчас смотрю в фиддле и такого нету там.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Fw5Ofe2.png

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark

Comment: Извините, но какая разница как рисовать маркер, если суть вопроса в координатах? Точка находится не там, где я ее ожидаю.

Comment: Как я понял желаемый результат вам не будет, посмотрите здесь в примере яндекса. когда там поставлено например `Нижний новгород`. оно совподает с картой на яндексе, а когда постовляешь другое имя оно уже может не совподать. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/direct_geocode

Comment: Я понимаю, что может не совпадать. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы совпадало? В этом и состоит мой вопрос (именно такое требование выдвинул заказчик).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Геокодер предназначен для конвертации *адресов* в координаты и наоборот. Найти *организацию* через Геокодер нельзя, т.к. он не является поиском и решает другую задачу.

Вам нужно использовать Геопоиск (API Поиска по организациям). В зависимости от Вашей задачи можно просто [добавить поисковую строку](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/search_control_ppo?from=SO) с предзаполненным запросом или использовать [HTTP API Геопоиска](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch?from=SO). Второй вариант необходим, если Вы хотите сами выбирать способ отображения объекта на карте (кастомная метка, своя карточка и .т.п).

Comment: А можно ли использовать autocomplete в геокодер http апи?

Comment: В http api нет саджеста и сам он не умеет дополнять частичный ввод, так что скорее нет — придётся использовать suggestView из JS API, а если без UI, то никак